# Wrap bytes data

Tags: objective-c

I need to wrap a string into a sequence of bytes according to a pattern:

1. First byte should be `0x02`
2. The second byte and the third byte should be the length of the string in bytes
3. Then the string sequence of bytes should come
4. Next byte should be `0x03`
5. Last byte should be the logical XOR of the bytes sequence of the string

This is what I tried to do:

```
- (NSData *)sendMessage:(NSData *)message {
    Byte stx = 0x02;
    Byte etx = 0x03;
    Byte length = [message length];

    // Computes bitwise XOR of message bytes
    const char *bytes = [message bytes];
    Byte crc = bytes[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < [message length]; i++)
        crc = crc ^ bytes[i];

    NSString *packet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x%x%s%x%x", stx, (uint16_t)length, bytes, etx, crc];
    return [packet dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
}
```

I need to write this bytes sequence into a `CBCharacteristic` that gets then read by a BT device, checks the format and, if it's correct, display the string. Anyway, it keeps rejecting it. Could someone please explain me where do I fail?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of `stringWithFormat` to build the data. That string and its resulting UTF-8 encoding is not at all what you need.

Use `NSMutableData` to add the bytes:

```
NSMutableData *result = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[result appendBytes:&stx length:1];
uint16_t len = (uint16_t)length;
[result appendBytes:&len length:2]; // might have a byte ordering issue here
[result appendData:message];
[result appendBytes:&crc length:1];
```